# Python log output in a file

Tags: python, ubuntu

I have a python function which prints some lines on terminal.

Here is how I execute the function:

```
python3 test.py
```

Here is some code from the file:

```
column1 = "|=========="
        column2 = "|==============================================================="
        column3 = "|==================================="
        column4 = "|======================="

        print("\n"+column1+column2+column3+column4+"|")
        print("|SCRIPT ID    |SCRIPT NAME                                                       |Start Time                         |RUN ID             |")
        print(column1+column2+column3+column4+"|")
```

It prints the following in terminal:

```
|==========|===============================================================|===================================|=======================|
|SCRIPT ID    |SCRIPT NAME                                                       |Start Time                         | RUN ID             |
|==========|===============================================================|===================================|=======================|
|1         |TEST_SCRIPT                                    |2020-04-17 11:46:28.054074+05:30   |201                    |
|==========|===============================================================|===================================|=======================|

Entering - SCRIPT
     Verification Started
     Verification Completed in 0 Hours 00 Min 00.000602 sec
     Methods Execution Started
     Methods Execution Completed
EXITING - SCRIPT
```

I want to maintain the output of the function in a log file. So, if I run `python3 test.py`, it should create a file called `test.py-202004171148.log` in a folder called as `logs` storing all the output in the file.

How can I do this?

Comment: provide some code from test.py

Comment: added some code from the file.

Comment: You could just do, python3 test.py > filename.log

Comment: do you want save `test.py-202004171148.log` with timestamp or just random numbers?

Comment: Is it possible to generate the file without writing filename.log every time?

Comment: Timestamp -  `test.py-202004171148.log`

Comment: You can write a bash script to construct a filename by using the current system time

Comment: @RishiDev can you please help me how?

Comment: @dang I have written a couple of lines that you can add to your script, as an answer. Hope it helps

Answer (score 3):

save file with datetime:

```
import datetime
file = open(str(datetime.now().strftime('test.py-%Y%m%d%H%M%S.log')), "w")
file.write("yourlogs")
file.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

to saving file you can use:

```
import datetime
file = open("test.py-"+str(datetime.datetime.now().timestamp())+".log", "w")
file.write("yourlogs")
file.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding these few lines of code to the top of your script should redirect all output to be printed to console AND ALSO written to a file

```
import sys
import datetime

class Printer(object):
    def __init__(self, *files):
        self.files = files
    def write(self, obj):
        for file in self.files:
            file.write(obj)
            file.flush()
    def flush(self):
        for file in self.files:
            file.flush()

f = open(f"{__file__}-{datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S')}.log", 'w')
sys.stdout = Printer(sys.stdout, f)

#Your print statements below
print("Hello world!")
```

Comment: Can we put the function name and put in the folder - logs

Comment: Also, can I print on screen and also save to file

Comment: Yes, you can create a folder logs, and save all your output to it. I will edit my answer to reflect the same.

Comment: Would be nice to get the filename dynamically. For example, if it is test.py-20200417.log or abc.py-20200427.log

Comment: You can access the filename in the variable `__file__`

Comment: Would this print on screen and store in the file?

Comment: This solution redirects the output to the file. I would have to modify my solution greatly, to accommodate both

Comment: The simplest solution would be to, write your log statements to a file using write() command like other answers suggest, and use the print() command to print to screen. This does seem repetitive, but it is the simplest solution

Comment: I actually like this one better so I don't have to modify any code. But I need to know how to display logs on terminal and store in logs.

Comment: @dang I have modified my answer. The code is a bit longer now. But it meets both your needs. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [logging](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/logging.html) module for that. You will have to replace `print()` with `logging.info()`, `logging.warning()`, or `logging.error()` depending on your desired log level.

```
import logging
from datetime import datetime
fn = datetime.now().strftime('logs/test.py-%Y%m%d%H%M%S.log')
logging.basicConfig(filename=fn, level=logging.INFO)
logging.info('Entering - SCRIPT')
logging.info('etc...')
```

The default format will prefix every message with the log level and logger name. If you don't want that, you can override it with `format`.

```
logging.basicConfig(filename=fn, level=logging.INFO, format='%(message)s')
```